# Delete Directories that Contain Specified File in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal, applescript

How do I delete a folder that contains a file or folder with a specific name?

E.g. I want to delete all folders that contain the file "things.txt":

```
/dirA/
/dirB/things.txt
/dirC/
/dirD/things.txt
/dirE/things.txt
/dirF/
```

It would then delete `dirB`, `dirD`, and `dirE` -- not just the files inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution without piping somewhere else would be to pass the directory name to a subshell in `find`'s `exec` function.

This will not be as efficient, and of course it'll try to remove directories that don't exist if they've already been deleted.

```
find . -depth -type f -name 'things.txt' -exec sh -c 'rm -rf "$(dirname $0)"' {} \;
```

If you want to use `xargs`, you could do it very simply like so. Note that `dirname` only takes one argument, so you have to specify `-n 1` to have `xargs` only pass one:

```
find . -depth -type f -name 'things.txt' | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq | xargs rm -rf
```

This will not be safe if your directory name contains a newline, so be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for these! One issue: When I tested the second one, `xargs -n 1` splits directory names with spaces in them, making it unusable. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: This worked with a few minor changes! Adding `-print0` to the find and `-0` to the xargs fixed the spaces issue, and since I decided I wanted to move everything to the trash and not delete it immediately, I ended up changing the xargs to `xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'filename=$(dirname "{}"); mv "$filename" "./Trash";'`

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

This has been tested on Linux as these commands below are also executable on Unix system.

`find -type f -name 'things.txt' | xargs dirname | xargs rm -r`

Explanation:

`find -type f -name 'things.txt'`  --> search for file named 'things.txt' (file only, not directory)

`|` --> piping the result to next command

`xargs dirname` | --> grabbing the directory name the file is located in then pipe the result to next command

`xargs rm -r`  --> proceed to remove all of these directories that has the file by name of 'things.txt'

Voila!

Comment: When you pipe from `find` to `xargs`, please use `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: It have resulted as this: `rm: cannont remove './DirD\n./DirB\n./DirE\n': No such file or directory`.  with `-0`, it is preventing bash from looping all files with sets of functions combined?

Comment: Actually, have you tested your command? It should return the error `dirname: extra operand `... things.txt'`.

Comment: Then it must be because of different version of bash im using.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You'd need to tell `xargs` to only pass one argument to `dirname` (see my answer). There could be different default behavior depending on your utility versions. OS X is a bit different than Linux in this regard.

Comment: You are correct.  This is linux based.  I stand corrected, hence my comment is for Linux, in case folks were looking for that.  Thank you, @slhck